# Getting started with a SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have been given a skeleton SBT project to work on. The directory structure is as follows:

```
|-- build.sbt
|-- project
|   |-- build.properties
|   |-- plugins.sbt
|   |-- project
|   `-- target
|-- README.md
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- scala
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- app-name
    |               |-- domain
    |               |-- exception
    |               |-- repository
    |               `-- util
    `-- test
        `-- scala
`-- Vagrantfile
```

The instructions are to create an app entry point which should take a single command line argument and run some logic.

I have managed to get a simple "hello world" sbt project working but I'm new to scala/sbt. Where would I place this entry point and how can I accept a command line argument?

Comment: passing params as simple as: run param1 param2 .. etc what do you mean by entry point? object with App trait extension?

Answer (score 1):

The root folder for source files would be `src/main/scala`.

Parameters are referenced using the `args` array within your entry point object.

The entry point is any object under that source tree which `extends App`. Since this is a hello world example and you're just getting started, I'd drop it right into the root of the sources (`src/main/scala/MyApp.scala`).

Something like this:

```
object MyApp extends App {
    println(args.length match {
        case 0 => "You passed in no arguments!"
        case 1 => s"You passed in 1 argument, which was ${args(0)}"
        case x => s"You passed in $x arguments! They are: ${args.mkString(",")}"
    })
}
```

To run your app, issue the `sbt run` command in the project root. To run with parameters, do `sbt run "arg1"`.

Comment: Oh, that looks like a separate issue with your environment/installation... Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to Scala & sbt myself, and that's not something I have the knowledge to help with. What happens if you run `sbt console`?

Comment: OK, I think I sorted out my environment but when I run your code I get a compile error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Comment: actually when you are within sbt you should do `run arg1 arg2` or `run "arg1" "arg2"` or from shell `sbt "run arg1 arg2"`. What you proposed would pass just single argument `"arg1 arg2"`

Comment: Even with 1 argument I still get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any ideas?

Comment: @harryg I updated the example with a more interesting exercise :) The new version should also work with any number of parameters.